# Exclude Entire Page if Conditions Not Met

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on a donation receipt project right now and have been asked to have the query exclude certain results. I am to generate receipts based on total donations given over the calendar year of 2015. I should note I am working off of a legacy report generated by my predecessor, so this is not written entirely by me. I am also not very experienced in Crystal, as you'll probably conclude for yourself.

Here is where the issue lies: Our database does not have a "Total Amount Given" field to easily exclude the results I don't want. The field "Amount" only checks individual donations made, which my predecessor then used a running total field to generate a total on each receipt. I have been asked to modify this report to only include people who have given over $1000 total. When I tried to work in a sum operator to the record selection area, it wouldn't allow me to do so. This report is creating a new page for each receipt, which is relevant.

My question here is this: How can I tell Crystal that when the running total is <1000 to exclude the receipt page entirely?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Use the field data is grouped on for {donorField}
then in Report > Selection Formulas > Group enter:

```
sum({YourTableAmountField},{DonorField}) > 999
```

Comment: I get an error message reading "This field cannot be used because it must be evaluated later", which is the same error I get when trying to use Sum in the record selection.

Comment: can you tell if there is a need for the running total? Can it just be summed at the group level? If so you can use that group total in the Report > Selection Formula > Group

Comment: I believe there is a need, as the report is pulling individual records of donations, listing them, then totaling them at the bottom. A running total is the only way I can see to get the total donation amount.